# Show Category icon in REST API wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I used ACF to add category icon to categories as ACF, and it have been added successfully,
now I want to show this field in REST API output :
I used this code but it does not work.
get_field and get_field_object simply returns null in the REST API output (see attached image)
and this is the live output :
http://134.209.149.245/index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/categories

```
function wpse_2879312_register_category_icon_field()
{
    register_rest_field(
        array('category'),
        'category_icon',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'wpse_2879312_get_category_icon',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'wpse_2879312_register_category_icon_field');

function wpse_2879312_get_category_icon($object, $field_name, $request)
{

    $category_icon = get_field_object('category_icon' , get_the_ID());
    return $category_icon ['value'];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is a very good plugin to expose your ACF fields
https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/
will save you a lot of time and works very well.